# Delete lines that are not n consecutive lines starting with the same id

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I have a file that looks like this:

```
194104,41.8,38.3
194104,46.7,39.6
194104,47.4,39.7
194104,49.8,44.3
194104,50.8,47.5
194136,39.9,36.3
194136,45.2,37.8
194170,46.9,42.2
...
```

I want to keep the six first lines, starting with 194104, and then delete the next two lines, because there are only two lines starting with that number. And so on for the rest of the file.

Can this be done with sed/awk/grep or other unix tools?

Comment: What is there's a ID with 7 lines?

Comment: @glennjackman In my case, that will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

> **Can this be done with sed/awk/grep or other unix tools?**

Yes.

...

It can be done using tools like awk or perl in about 20 lines of code.

```
$ cat t.txt
194104,41.8,38.3
194104,46.7,39.6
194104,47.4,39.7
194104,49.8,44.3
194104,50.8,47.5
194136,39.9,36.3
194136,45.2,37.8
194170,46.9,42.2

$ perl t.pl t.txt
194104,41.8,38.3
194104,46.7,39.6
194104,47.4,39.7
194104,49.8,44.3
194104,50.8,47.5

$ wc -l t.pl
19 t.pl
```

The basic ideas I used were

- loop over input a line at a time
- append the lines to a buffer
- check the value of the first word
- keep a count of how many times it had been seen
- if different, decide if to print and flush buffer, reset count

---

Pseudocode

This corresponds line by line with my perl code but perl is a bit terser
(and I cuddle my elses even though Larry disapproves).

```
let my minimum be 5
let my buffer be blank
let my count be zero
let my prior first word be blank

while read a line

   if there is a numeric first word followed by a comma 
   then
      if that first word was the same as my prior first word
      then
         increment my count
      otherwise
         if my count is greater than or equal to my minimum
         then
           print my buffer
         end if
         empty my buffer
         let my count be one
      end if
      let my prior first word be the one I just read
      append the line I just read to my buffer
   end if
end while
```

It can probably be done in fewer lines or a longish one-liner.

Comment: Should have said "_How_ can this be done?", I guess, haha. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The specification may be ambiguous a bit because it's not clear if you wish exactly or at least six lines with the same prefix. On the other hand, in your example there are only 5 lines of that kind in the head which caused some confusion (I should count before I shoot) when I tested this:

```
$ cat 6lines.awk
$1 == prev {
   ++cnt
   block = block $0 RS
   if (cnt == 6) {
      printf block
      cnt = 0
      block = ""
   }
   next
}

{
   block = $0 RS
   prev = $1
   cnt = 1
}
```

awk -F, -f 6lines.awk input

We exploit that awk takes everything not assigned like an empty string (prev here).

Comment: Oh wow, you're exactly right, I should have counted those properly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
perl -F, -ane '
    if ($. > 1) {
        if (@q == 6) { print @q; undef @q }
        elsif ($F[0] ne $prev) { undef @q }
    }
    push @q, $_;
    $prev = $F[0];
    END { if (@q == 6) {print @q} }
'
```